# "Classpath is incomplete" warning still appear even though a build.gradle exist

Tags: java, spring, gradle, visual-studio-code

From what I understand [here](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/%22Classpath-is-incomplete%22-warning), the "Classpath is incomplete" warning will not appear if I open a folder which has build.gradle file in it.

In my case, I have a build.gradle file but still the pop up appear.

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'hello.HelloWorld'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
}

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-gradle'
    version = '0.1.0'
}
```

Did I missing something?

Please bear with me this is my first time with Gradle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same, and fixed it by adding the following to my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```